# Regex cant match all data between repeated character

Tags: regex, string, regex-greedy

I wanted to match the data in between `"@@@"` characters

```
@@@haha@@@hoho@@@hehe@@@hihi@@@
```

regex:

```
@@@(.*?)@@@
```

By using this regex, I am only able to get `haha` and `hehe`, which are the 1st and 3rd matches. How to match all the 4 data in between `@@@`?

Comment: Using `/([^@]+)/` should do it.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, not when the requirement is that there are at least 3 `@` before and after each match.

Comment: @trincot For the provided data, this is more than enough. There isn't anything saying that there is going to be 1-2 loose `@` and what to do with them.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, sure, but I suppose the data is dynamic, otherwise there is no sense in using a search at all.

Comment: Unless the O.P. specifies, it is just an assumption. You assume the data may change, I assume that that is the format. Obviously, mine could be wrong while yours is right no matter what. That's why I wrote a comment and you an answer. Now, the O.P. should specify the missing piece.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use look ahead to avoid that you grab the characters that you might still need to see in a next match:

[`@@@(.*?)(?=@@@)`](https://regex101.com/r/LUWt77/1)